# What is a probability of coin being loaded?

Tags: probability, bayesian, bayes-theorem

We have two coins: one is fair, and the other one is loaded with probability of $70\%$ coming head. Suppose we randomly chose a coin with prior probability of $60\%$ being a loaded one and flipped it $5$ times, and the result was $2$ heads $3$ tails. What is probability we chose a loaded coin?

Comment: Do you know Bayes' rule? It is the tool to be used in this problem.

Comment: i know but my calculation result is 0.4448 but the answer seems to be 0.388

Comment: Ah, ok. Now what you need to do is show your working. This way, we will be able to point out *where*  you made a mistake. This is clearly more important than giving you a straight answer, since the correction of your thought process will leave you in a better position than merely showing the answer.

Comment: p(loaded | H=2)=p(H=2| loaded)*.6/p(H=2) 
,p(H=2)= 10*(.5)^5+10*(.7)^2*(.3)^3
,p(H=2| loaded) = 10*(.7)^2*(.3)^3

Comment: It's still not clear. Please use the MathJax reference page to format your equations. I don't want to get your statements wrong, that's why I'm asking for clarity. If you do so, I shall upvote this question as well in appreciation of your effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try to decrypt your attempt. So you have

$$P(\text{"loaded coin"}|H=2)=\frac{p(H=2| \text{"loaded coin"})\cdot P(\text{"loaded coin"})}{P(H=2)},$$

where $P(\text{"loaded coin"})=0.6$

$$ P(H=2| \text{"loaded coin"}) = 10\cdot 0.7^2\cdot 0.3^3$$

That´s correct. Additionally we have

$$ P(H=2| \text{"fair coin"}) = 10\cdot 0.5^2\cdot 0.5^3$$

Now we can use the Law of total probability: $P(H=2)$

$$=P(\text{"loaded coin"})\cdot P(H=2| \text{"loaded coin"})+P(\text{"fair coin"})\cdot P(H=2| \text{"fair coin"})$$

$=0.6\cdot 10\cdot 0.7^2\cdot 0.3^3+0.4\cdot 10\cdot 0.5^2\cdot 0.5^3$. Finally we get

$$P(\text{"loaded coin"}|H=2)=\frac{0.6\cdot 10\cdot 0.7^2\cdot 0.3^3}{0.6\cdot 10\cdot 0.7^2\cdot 0.3^3+0.4\cdot 10\cdot 0.5^2\cdot 0.5^3}=38.84\%$$

Comment: Peculiar use of the word *encrypt*.

Comment: Oh, Oh, Oh. Good catch. I wanted to write decrypt. I hope it´s better!?